# How to check empty variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have JSON file like below:

```
[{"url":null,"id":null},{"url":"bHo2M0V6ZzdOK0JPUFFSRG16ZHErRUJSWTRCQmxIY2lTL0I3Z2xkeVpnZHpRODRaaHZhOFR6S3VLZFpSaXpsWkVvY25jNDZIZGdJbzl3UE9MZGtmSXBsbHVvLzZuOXB5WXBYWS9VTk03dXM9","id":"7c1335b69b2b4a037b3474da1fab2bbe"}]
```

Now I am using `javascript` to parse this JSON file extract values from it. The code for same is:

```
<script>

<!-- This functions matches query string from URL-->

function getQuery(query) {
  var pReg = new RegExp(query + "\\=([^\\?&]+)", "i");
  if (!pReg.test(window.location.href)) {
    return '';
  }
  var pRes = pReg.exec(window['location']['href']);
    return decodeURIComponent(pRes[1]);
  }

<!-- This function parse JSON -->
function parseJSON() {
  fetch(`cache.json`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(resJSON => sendData(resJSON))
  .catch(console.error);

<!-- Now this function here, grabs "query string" from "url" and passes it in below function. After that it "searches" that "URL" in "parsed JSON" file above and returns the "id" associated with it. -->

var url;
url = getQuery('url')
function sendData(jsonObj){
  for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){
    if(jsonObj[i].url == url){
      var id = jsonObj[i].id;

    }
  }
}
```

I have explained what above functions do, now coming to question, when I pass a `URL` as `query string` which is not present is above JSON file, it will now not return any `id` because it doesn't have value associated with it. It does same, it doesn't return anything. But then, when this happens I want to log it. For same, I did this:

```
1.

var url;
url = getQuery('url')
function sendData(jsonObj){
  for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){
    if(jsonObj[i].url == url){
      var id = jsonObj[i].id;
      if(id){
        console.log("exists");
      } else { 
        console.log("not exists");
      }
    }
  }
}

OR

2. 

var url;
url = getQuery('url')
function sendData(jsonObj){
  for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){
    if(jsonObj[i].url == url){
      var id = jsonObj[i].id;
      if(typeof id === 'undefined'){
        console.log("not  exists");
      } else { 
        console.log("exists");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it is not logging anything when passing `URL` as `query string` which does exits in JSON file. Though it logs perfectly when an `id` is associated with `URL`. So I guess the code is not wrong. If their is something wrong please point it out.

Comment: do you want output for the "null" id? than check if(id === null)

Comment: @Mouri No, Not just `null id` . Any `URL` when passed but is not present in `JSON file`, it should `log it` but it is not doing it. it follows following logic: If url passed is not present in `JSON` so, it won't have any `id`, which amounts to `null`. But still when passed `(id === null){}` it doesn't logs.

Comment: than at first check if ( url === ' ') .....because you are checking this through getQuery() function and it returns ' ' if the url dont exist in the json file.

Comment: @Mouri can you explain what are you trying to say. variable `url` will always be present. So it doesn't make any sense of checking `url`

Comment: i am talking about the var url = getQuery(url) .... you should check this url variable. doesnt it will be ' ' if the url doesn't exist in the json file?

Comment: @Mouri I understand. But I will further create a code that will write `url query` if it is not present in `JSON` file and it will create a `id` if `url` is valid. So I cannot rule out `url` at first

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do. if the url does not exist in the json file than you want to block it right?  than what is the problem to rule out url first!

Comment: @Mouri No, if it is not present, then it will take that `url` decode it and will check if that url has valid `id` and if `url` is not valid then it won't write. But if valid it will write. So you see `url` cannot be ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

Your first answer should work and also it is better to use let instead of var when using for loops. Try logging the json object inside for loop.
Tried like below and It seems to work.

```
var jsonObj = [{"url":"abc","id":null},{"url":"abc","id":"7c1335b69b2b4a037b3474da1fab2bbe"}];
var url = "abc"
console.log(jsonObj.length);
for (let i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
  let temp = jsonObj[i];
  console.log(temp);  
  if (temp.url === url) {
    let id = jsonObj[i].id;
    if(!id){
      console.log("not exists");
    } else {
      console.log("exists");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain that in more detail.

Comment: it worked because you took `url` as `abc` in both instances

Comment: it doesnt matter, not sure what's not working

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jsonObj = [{"url":"abc","id":null},{"url":"bHo2M0V6ZzdOK0JPUFFSRG16ZHErRUJSWTRCQmxIY2lTL0I3Z2xkeVpnZHpRODRaaHZhOFR6S3VLZFpSaXpsWkVvY25jNDZIZGdJbzl3UE9MZGtmSXBsbHVvLzZuOXB5WXBYWS9VTk03dXM9","id":"7c1335b69b2b4a037b3474da1fab2bbe"}];
var url = "bHo2M0V6ZzdOK0JPUFFSRG16ZHErRUJSWTRCQmxIY2lTL0I3Z2xkeVpnZHpRODRaaHZhOFR6S3VLZFpSaXpsWkVvY25jNDZIZGdJbzl3UE9MZGtmSXBsbHVvLzZuOXB5WXBYWS9VTk03dXM9";
for (let i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
  if (jsonObj[i].url === url) {
    let id = jsonObj[i].id;
    if(id){
      console.log("exists");
    }
  } else {
      console.log("not exists");
    }
}
```

@Andy if it is your expected output [image: output]
Try this...

```
var url;
url = getQuery('url')
function sendData(jsonObj){
  for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){
    if(jsonObj[i].url === url){
      var id = jsonObj[i].id;
       if(id){
         console.log("exists");
       } 
    }else { 
         console.log("not exists");
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: Check following code hosted. This doesn't logs: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPH4351I8QSZ

Comment: I just have hosted code their so I could share it.

Comment: did you run the code snippet which i have included? isn't it your expected output?

Comment: You passed same `url` in `json` as well as `var url`. Try both as different and let me know what result you get. I already mentioned in question, when both are same, it does log but only when it is different it doesn't

Comment: than it return "not exists"

Comment: Have you run code snippet which i shared. Does it logs `not exists`? try that. The code you shared returns both exists as well as not exists because value `null` does not equals to `url` passed and `const url` and `url` in json match therefore `exists`

Comment: try my code with your input and than see the result

Comment: It's totally wrong. because it will check both value `null` as well as `url`. So it will log both exists as well as not exists. see now. Just try my code and share me results you are getting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231027/discussion-between-mouri-and-andy).